# Unable to subscribe to [ros-users] mailinglist

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am trying to subscribe to the ros users mailing list, i did confirm the subscription, and i got a confirmation/welcome mail, but I don't get any messages.  Do you know, what I can do, to get it work? I already checked my mail-space, spam-directory and so on.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122481/unable-to-subscribe-to-%5Bros-users%5D-mailinglist/) by [ingo_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/11241/ingo_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-26**:
Have you considered that there maybe just weren't any messages since you subscribed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you may have signed up for the old version of the mailing list. Make sure you are signed up for the new version of the list hosted on lists.ros.org. http://lists.ros.org/mailman/listinfo

We have migrated away from the hosting on code.ros.org, however the list is still available for archival purposes. I have added some more warnings on the subscription page and welcome email.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ingo_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/11241/ingo_k/) on 2014-01-27**:
thanks. thats it:)